# Could not be located in dynamic link library php4ts.dll

Tags: php, dll, php4

before it was working fine after installing dot net ..when i started wamp i am getting error as

```
The procedure entry point_object_and_properties_init could not be located in
dynamic link library php4ts.dll
```

When i check in

```
D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin

 php4ts.dll is not present there. So i take a copy of  php4ts.dll from
 D:\wamp\bin\php \php5.3.13\ext and paste it in    D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin
```

But still it showing same error

Comment: It seems that some invalid version of `php4ts.dll` is loaded from somewhere. Maybe dot net messed with PATH variable. Try to find `php4ts.dll` in system paths and compare their versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed port it worked..i changed the port in http.conf it worked...